# Row wise writing to file using fwrite() in Matlab

Tags: matlab, hex, fwrite

[image]fwrite in Matlab writes in column order. This is a problem for me as I need to write hex values which should be read byte wise and then go to the next row and so on. Is there a way this can be done? Below is my code.

```
hexvec = dec2hex(bytevec,2);
fileID = fopen('my_flipped_data_new.bin','wt');
fwrite(fileID, hexvec);
fclose(fileID);
```

Thanks!

Comment: two ways to solve your problem: 1) save the whole file in column order, re-read it, transverse the matrix and write it again; 2) get the full matrix you want to save in file and write in the desired orientation (do a transverse if needed). If your problem is more complex please provide an example.

Comment: Can you give an example to clarify, because right now it looks like transposing the matrix would solve your problem

Comment: @Nishant: yes it does to some extent but it treats it as continuous (see image above). I want it to go cell-wise i.e like 0F 4B 8C ...etc

Comment: Just to clarify: is this data supposed to be used in matlab later on, or are you trying to export it to another device/program? And in that case, how does this device/program work?

Comment: from your example it seems a transverse solves as you would therefore get 0F;4B;...

Comment: @all: yes this data will be used later on to a sram where it would go byte-wise.I want that each "matrix" or "cell" of Matlab holds the data byte-wise. basically, i want that data to look like a 1*something row array separated by spaces after each byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think I got your point.

CODE:

```
F=dec2hex(1:63,2);
F=[char(F),repmat(' ',length(F),1)]'
F=F(:)'
fileID = fopen('my_flipped_data_new.bin','wt');
fwrite(fileID, F);
fclose(fileID);
```

OUTPUT (text file):

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F
```

Comment: Yes, MATLAB writes files in **column-major** format.  As such, you need to take this into account and transpose your data if necessary.

Comment: @ASantosRiberio: I am getting this now.    Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in print_to_text (line 23)
F=[char(F),repmat(' ',length(F),1)]'

Comment: the code I wrote is correct. I do not know how did you implmented based on the error.

Answer (score 0):

@AsantosRiberio your code is correct; the only problem was with the length(F) which was giving the "index exceeds matrix dimensions" errors. To avoid this, simply use

```
[rw co] = size(new_converted);
new_converted=[char(new_converted),repmat(' ',**rw**,1)]';
```

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: sorry but I still cannot understand you problem. using the first dimension from size or the length of a matrix is exactly the same. see the example below. a=ones(3,2);
[rw,co]=size(a);
rw
length(a)

a=ones(5,2);
[rw,co]=size(a);
rw
length(a)

a=ones(7,2);
[rw,co]=size(a);
rw
length(a)

Comment: yes..i changed the name of the variable F also but the issue persisted...i guess this might be due to the class of the variable I've been using and length() might not work... for eg: when I did class(new_converted) it returned char then I did length(new_converted) and I get the same error...new_converted is the new name for F